# UITapGestureRecognizer to hide keyboard taps on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the below script, and when the keyboard is up, if I click around it in this UIController, it will hide the keyboard, but it will also click on the cell. I do not want that to happen.

I know that `cancelsTouchesInView` will control that feature... and if I set it to true, it wont click on the cell, BUT I can't click on the cell after the keyboard is hidden.

Is there a good solution for this?

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard2))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard2() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

[image: Keyboard presented]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to disable user interaction on your tableView when the keyboard is shown, and then re-enable it when you end editing.

However, you might give this a try and see if it does what you need.

Change your signature for the `dismissKeyboard2` func to get a reference to the tap gesture recognizer and remove it when you end editing:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard2(_:)))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard2(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        view.removeGestureRecognizer(g)
    }
}
```